# Nominalization is the name for the conversion of a word or a phrase into a noun. Is there a name for the conversion of a word into a question?

Tags: grammar

In Mong language, a word can be converted into a question by a prefix and suffix.  Puosmuaj is the prefix puos- with the infinitive to have muoj, meaning do you have it, is there anything appearing/happening there, etc.  Puossab is the prefix puos- with the adverb sab asking is it high.  Puoskim is the prefix puos- with the adjective kim asking if it is expensive.  Leejtwg is the classifier leej with the suffix -twg, asking which individual.  Thaumtwg would be a  duration thaum with the interrogative suffix -twg, at what time=when.  Qhovtwg is the article qhov with the suffix -twg=where.  Is there a name for this questioning conversion?

Comment: Many languages have interrogative words, particles, or affixes that convert statements, phrases, or words into questions. In Malay, one adds _-ku_ to an important word to form a yes/no question. In Lushootseed, one adds _-ʔu_ after the pronoun subject to get the same effect.

Comment: I am glad you inform us that there are more languages out there that form a question out of adding another morpheme to the base morpheme.  Since this is not an uncommon situation, shouldn't there be a name for it?  What would the process of this question forming be called?

Comment: Also, this questioning word doesn't necessarily have to always be used as a question only.  It can be used as a pronoun, conjunction, adverb, etc. depending on how you form your sentence.  I am curious about what is the process of turning a word into a question is called.

Comment: There's no special name for adding an interrogative morpheme, any more than there is for adding any other kind of morpheme. And interrogative affixes are just that -- they are not pronouns, usually, nor adverbs; they are their own kind of thing.